# Criteria API in Hibernate, multiple restrictions for same column in joining table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have  tables `person` and `personDoc` as below:

```
person :

personNo
dateofBirth
firstname
LastName
MiddleName
salutationCode

personDoc :

personNo
doctype
documentNo
```

I have to search person with name = "John" and (doctype = "passport" and documentNo = "XXXX') and (doctype = "Driving license" and documentNo= "YYYY")

I am using the criteria API to do the search.

I have joined the `person` and `persondoc` tables using alias.

How do I add restrictions (for the same table and column) more than once?

Note:for further scenarios, I need to search like:

person with name like "John" and (doctype = "passport" and documentNo = "XXXX') or (doctype = "Driving license" and documentNo= "YYYY").

Comment: @DieterMeemken  Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(PersonWrapper.class,"rel");
Criterion  firstName =  Restrictions.eq("rel.firstName",fName);
c.add(firstName);
for(PersonDocWraper pDocWrapper :argperSonWrapper.getRelationshipDocumentWrappers().values())
{
aliasName = "pDOC"+pDocWrapper .getDocumentTypeCode();
c.createAlias("pDocWrapper ", aliasName, JoinType.INNER_JOIN);
c.add(Restrictions.eq(aliasName.concat(".documentTypeCode"), pDocWrapper.getDocumentTypeCode()));
c.add(Restrictions.eq(aliasName.concat(".documentTypeValue"), pDocWrapper.getDocumentValue()));
}
returnList = c.list();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the following query with Criteria:

> person with name like "John" and (doctype = "passport" and documentNo
>   = "XXXX') or (doctype = "Driving license" and documentNo= "YYYY").

You can try with [Criteria's `Disjunction` and `Conjunction` feature](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)

Without looking how `Person` and `PersonDoc` tables are mapped using the `entity classes` it is difficult to build the exact criteria. But I hope below example should give you the hint on you can do it.

```
Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction(); //OR condition

Conjunction conjunction1  = Restrictions.conjunction(); //AND condition
conjunction1.add(Restrictions.eq("doc.doctype", "passport"));
conjunction1.add(Restrictions.eq("doc.documentNo", "XXXX"));

Conjunction conjunction2  = Restrictions.conjunction(); //AND condition
conjunction2.add(Restrictions.eq("doc.doctype", "Driving License"));
conjunction2.add(Restrictions.eq("doc.documentNo", "YYYY"));

disjunction.add(conjunction1);
disjunction.add(conjunction2);
```

And this disjunction can be used in criteria building (as an example):

```
session.createCriteria(Person.class, "p").createAlias(.., "doc").
add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.like("p.name", "John"),   disjunction)).   
setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Added `setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)` to make sure it returns only distinct `Person` entities.

Note that we can achieve the same using `Restrictions.and` and `Restrictions.or`as well.

If this doesn't help, do post entities related to `Person` and `PersonDoc` tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot for Ur inputs. Would try and let u know.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this like following:

```
Root<Person> r = cq.from(Person.class);
Root<PersonDoc> p = cq.from(PersonDoc.class);
cq.where(
   cb.and(
      cb.equal(r.get(Person_.name), "John"),     
      cb.or(
        cb.and(
           cb.equal(p.get(PersonDoc_.doctype), "passport"), 
           cb.equal(p.get(PersonDoc_.documentNo), "XXXX")
        ), 
        cb.and(
           cb.equal(p.get(PersonDoc_.doctype), "driverLicense"), 
           cb.equal(p.get(PersonDoc_.documentNo), "XXXX")
        )
      ),  
      cb.equal(p.get(PersonDoc_.person), r)
   );
```

Comment: We are not using JPA , we are using hibernate and i am trying to Criteria API as it involves dynamic searching.

Comment: Then replace type safe jpa's criteria calls with not type safe calls of pure hibernate. The approach is same: not join but multiple roots. And proper merging of "and" and "or" statements